# Spring Security 5 with Netty

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, netty

Got a problem with authentication configuration with `Spring Security 5.0.0.RC1` in a `Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6` application. All the samples I've managed to find are being based on `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` (like this [one](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.0.0.RC1/samples/boot/oauth2login/src/main/java/sample/config/OAuth2LoginConfig.java#L31) for example), which on it's turn depends on the `javax.servlet.Filter`. As `spring-boot-starter-webflux` by default goes with Netty, expectedly there is no Servlet API implementation included, so the configuration done this way can't even be compiled.

Am I missing some Netty-compatible way of having authentication configured?

Comment: Where do you read that Netty is the default? And what is the problem to add Servlet API dependencies to your project?

Comment: Sorry, I've meant that Spring Webflux has a default dependency on Netty (`Compile Dependencies` https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-webflux/2.0.0.M6). I've edited the question to make it more clear.  

There's no problem to add the API as a dependency, but Netty doesn't provide an implementation of this API (like Tomcat is doing). I know I can switch on Tomcat but if trying to follow reactive approach, Netty seems like worth to be given a chance.

Comment: You answered my first comment, but why can't you add the servlet API as dependency? I guess, you don't know, that Spring Security uses `Filter` but not in a servlet manner, just as a interface. Spring Security's filters are added to Spring Security's own filter chain.

Comment: It doesn't look like having only the `Filter` is enough, so if you know the actual working example that would help if you shared it fully.
With `compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0'`
The application startup fails with `Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean`. Which is also expected, as the implementations of the `ServletWebServerFactory` are being provided only by Tomcat, Jetty and Undertow.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know an example. Both are just milestones not final releases. You have to wait until both are final and some examples are provided. But you can already read a [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#security) and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Security-2.0).

Comment: @Vadim Chekry, did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: Not really, ended up switching to Undertow